# An error has occurred that says {"code":"BadArgument","requestId":"XXXX","message":"JSON format error."} on computer vision api of Azure

Tags: ruby, azure, computer-vision

```
     require 'net/http'

    uri = URI('https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/vision/v1.0/analyze')
    uri.query = URI.encode_www_form({
        # Request parameters
        'visualFeatures' => 'Adult',
        'details' => 'Celebrities',
        'language' => 'en'
    })

    request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.request_uri)
    # Request headers
    request['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
    # Request headers
    request['Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key'] = 'caa91cccdgywtduwdxxf530'
    # Request body
    request.body = "http://instudy.jp/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/doraemon-coming.jpg"

    response = Net::HTTP.start(uri.host, uri.port, :use_ssl => uri.scheme == 'https') do |http|
        http.request(request)
    end

    puts response.body
```

I wanted to  check the photo whether adult things or not so I wrote the code.
I think there is nothing wrong so I don't know why error's occurred.

**environment**: `ruby 2.3.1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the [documentaion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/azure/cognitive-services/computer-vision/quickstarts/ruby), the vision api is expecting an image url in 'url' key of request body. Also in your case, you are not passing a valid json as request body. So, replace

```
request.body = "http://instudy.jp/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/doraemon-coming.jpg"
```

with

```
request_body = Hash.new
request_body[:url] = "http://instudy.jp/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/doraemon-coming.jpg"
request.body = request_body.to_json
```

Comment: Thanks to you,I could realize , but is there clearer code?

Comment: request.body = "{\"url\": \"http://instudy.jp/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/doraemon-coming.jpg\"}" isn't easy to read.

Comment: Thanks i really appreciate to you.

Comment: `{url: "http://instudy.jp/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/doraemon-coming.jpg"}.to_json`?

Comment: >>mudasobwa  I couldn't realize that with your code

Comment: If you cant understand what @mudasobwa suggested, then you will have to go through some ruby tutorials.

Comment: Sajin sorry I had error so if you can't Im gonna sit still.

Comment: I've already edited the answer with the easiest solution I can give.

Comment: No, your latest code makes an error undefined method `to_json' for #<Hash:0x007fa876a9dfa0> (NoMethodError)
Did you mean?  to_s

Comment: @RyuNishida That's because you have not given `require 'json'`. Since you are working with json data, I thought you had already given that

Comment: As you told me! I could do that